# What is the meaning of the caution in hardware manual of a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to understand the hardware manual of a microcontroller. Here is one caution in this manual:

"The behavior and performance are not guaranteed when the alternative functions are not assigned to the register"

This caution appears with a table describing the alternative functions of several pins in a register. 
Here is the image of the caution in the hardware manual: [image]

I don't understand the meaning of this caution. If an alternative function is not assigned to the register, we just simply can not use this register as the alternative function. Why do they say that behavior and performance are not guaranteed?

Does it mean that we can still use a register as an alternative function even when the alternative function is not assigned to the register? The only problem is the performance is not ensured?

Comment: It means that using the register like this is undefined behavior, and the chip could do just about anything, and it might change between individual chips.

Comment: It means do not use the registers that way because they did not go to the effort to design in circuitry predictable, reliable behaviour for this unintended use nor did they bother trying to figure out or characterize what happens. Every last detail requires circuitry to be built (even the "regular" stuff for general use of a register), and it's not just there by default because you want it to be. For example, saving circuitry can cause things like registers being changed when stuff happens elsewhere on the chip. Even a register holding its value is something that has to be designed in.

Comment: @Toor "It means do not use the registers *that* way". Which way exactly? If you really read the context from the question and the text from the datasheet, that really isn't clear. But if you are able to clarify this detail, that would probably be the answer OP expects. We all know what "The behavior and performance are not guaranteed" means. It's the other part that needs to be clarified.

Comment: @dim In the way the datasheet warns not to (assigning something other than the specified alternative functions to the register, for example, using it to store some extraneous value for future use because undefined values may run off and affect other things in the chip rather than just sitting safely in the register, isolated and doing nothing due to shortcuts taken in circuitry).

Comment: @Toor "storing extraneous values for future uses"? For me, the warning in the datasheet implies that all alternative functions registers should always be assigned at startup. You see, we don't interpret it the same way. I don't pretend to have the right interpretation, but you have to agree it's really not that clear. Elliot has a slightly different interpretation too (he's probably right).

Comment: @dim All three of our interpretations are the same. Just Elliot's is general perspective, yours is action oriented, and mine is example driven. The OP asked "If an alternative function is not assigned to the register, we just simply can not use this register as the alternative function". That implies he thinks he can write nonsense values in the register and just have it safely sit in there with the system ignoring it. The only practical reason for that is to use it as a fast-access storage register.

Comment: Opinion :-) : You said "If an alternative function is not assigned to the register, we just simply can not use this register as the alternative function" -> NO!. Rather, we cannot safely use it for ANY function. It's unlikely but, worst case, reading or writing it MIGHT do anything conceivable. Reading it reapeatedly may not give the same value. Writing to it MAY affect something else and/or not store the value. ...

Comment: What is the part number? Link to the hardware manual? Could be useful to look at more of the surrounding text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual is poorly written, but I think what they are trying to say is that if you do not program the register for a documented alternate function then the behavior will be undefined. For example, I would assume that programming any of the registers for the 3rd, 4th, or 5th alternative would result in unpredictable behavior at pins JP0_0 through JP0_6. Likewise, that the behavior of pin JP0_6 is unpredictable for any of the alternate modes.

However, the OP should provide a link to the original document. There is almost certainly some important context that is missing from the question.